# Sideways headers and page numbering

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, page-numbering

I was browsing the web to find some design inspiration for a report I'm working on, and I found this two examples of headers and page numbering at the side of the pages rather than on the top and bottom.

The cover of the [Fogli Magazine, Associazione Biblioteca Salita dei Frati](http://www.bibliotecafratilugano.ch), which one can download from their website:

[image: Cover]

And a Title Page.

[image: Article Start]

A page with no title. 
[image: Page]

[Here](https://www.behance.net/gallery/17369483/A-TypeExpedition) is a similar example over on Bechance.

I'm particularly interested in the first one. Does anyone know a way to implement such a header/page numbering layout in LaTeX/XeLaTeX?

As a quick and filthy solution I came up with this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{everypage,tikz,blindtext}

% Option for title page:
\newif\ifplainst

% Clear page style:
\pagestyle{empty}

% A new(ish) section command:
\let\oldsection\section
\def\sectionname{\thetitle}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
    \oldsection{#1}
    \renewcommand{\sectionname}{#1}
}%

% The sideways header:
\AddEverypageHook{%
    \ifplainst
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
            % Node with the page number
            \node[anchor=north,rotate=-90,yshift=-5ex] at (current page.-45)
            {\thepage};
        }%
    \else
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%           
        % First node with the section number and name
            \node[anchor=north,rotate=-90,yshift=-5ex,xshift=6ex] at (current page.45)
            {\textsection \hspace{2pt} \thesection \hspace{2pt} \dots
                \hspace{4pt} \sectionname};
            % Second node with the pagenumber
            \node[anchor=north,rotate=-90,yshift=-5ex] at (current page.-45)
            {\thepage};
        }%<- End of \tikz
    \fi
}% <- end of \AddEverypageHook

\begin{document}

    \plainsttrue
    \section{Sample Section}
    \Blindtext[5]


    \plainstfalse
    \Blindtext[2]


\end{document}
```

This Gives:

[image]
[image: Page No Title]

Does anyone have another, perhaps better solution?

Answer (score 2):

I do not really understand what the required result is, but it should be possible with package `scrlayer-scrpage`. This package defines its page styles using layers. So it is possible to define new layers and add them to page styles.

```
\documentclass[a4paper
  ,twoside
]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[markcase=noupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[section]{section}
\renewcommand\sectionmarkformat{\textsection \hspace{2pt} \thesection \hspace{2pt} \dots\hspace{4pt}}

% remove the default contents of header and footer for pagestyles scrheadings and plain
\clearpairofpagestyles

% add new layers to scrheadings and plain.scrheadings (note that plain is an alias for plain.scrheadings}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{margin.even,margin.odd}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{plain.margin.even,plain.margin.odd}

% define the new layers in the outer margin
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  evenpage,
  textarea,
  addhoffset=\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax,
  width=\marginparwidth,
  contents={\rotatebox{90}{%
    \parbox{\layerheight}{%
      \pagemark\hfill
      \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\layerheight-4em\relax}{\raggedleft\headmark}%
  }}}
]{margin.even}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,
  textarea,
  addhoffset=\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep\relax,
  width=\marginparwidth,
  contents={\hfill\rotatebox[origin=Br]{-90}{%
    \parbox{\textheight}{%
      \parbox[t]{10cm}{\raggedright\headmark}%
      \hfill
      \pagemark
  }}}
]{margin.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=margin.even,
  contents={\rotatebox{90}{%
    \parbox{\layerheight}{\pagemark\hfill}
  }}
]{plain.margin.even}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=margin.odd,
  contents={\hfill\rotatebox[origin=Br]{-90}{%
    \parbox{\layerheight}{\hfill\pagemark}
  }}
]{plain.margin.odd}

\begin{document}
    \section{Sample Section}\thispagestyle{plain}
    \Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]